# React-router and redux manual URL enter error

Tags: reactjs, routes, redux, react-router, react-redux

i have a problem of undefined props from redux store.
here is my `routeHandler` file

```
function organisationsFromStore(store) {
  const { router, organisations } = store;
  return {
    organisations
  }
}

function organisationFromStore(store) {
  const { router, organisations } = store;
  const { organisationId } = router.params;
  return {
    organisation: organisations.get(parseInt(organisationId))
  }
}


export const organisationRouteHandler = connect(organisationFromStore)(Organisation);
export const accountsConfigurationRouteHandler = connect(organisationsFromStore)(AccountsConfiguration);
```

This is hooked to my `getRoutes.jsx` file which handles routes:

```
<Route path="accounts" component={accountsConfigurationRouteHandler}>
   <Route path=":organisationId" component={organisationRouteHandler}></Route>
</Route>
```

In my `Organisation.jsx`(which gets `organisations` prop from it's parent `AccountsConfiguration`) component i have:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div style={{display: "inline"}}>
        <div className={styles.desks}>
          <span className={deskStyles.desksLabel}>Desks</span>
          <ul className={deskStyles.desksList}>
            {
              this.props.organisation.get("desks").map(desk => {
                return <li>{desk.get("name")}</li>;
              })
            }
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div className={this.state.childrenStyle}>
          {this.props.children}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
```

When i thy to enter my URL manually `e.g localhost:1234/accounts/4` (4 being the `organisationId`), i get the error saying `this.props.organisations is not defined`, which breaks the app. This is happening because first route's handler (`organisationsFromStore`) did not store the `organisations` and it didn't pass it as prop to `AccountsConfiguration`, which then didn't pass it to `Organisations` via `this.props.children`.

What is the best way to make the component wait for all the previous routes to get their props, and then render in this case `Organisation` component without error? Or is there a better way of doing this. Hope i was clear, thanks.

P.S I'm using old redux-router version before v2, and it must be that version at this time.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my mind wasn't working properly yesterday, i just inserted check if props are defined and rendered it conditionaly `this.props.organisation ? .... : null`